# How can a sorcerer be treated as being in a different terrain?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, sorcerer, terrain

A sorcerer that possesses the archetype [stone warder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/stone-warder-sorcerer/) is at his best in hills, mountains, and underground terrain.

How can a stone warder ensure that he is in such terrain even when he otherwise isn't? For example, how can a stone warder in a town be treated as being in the hills?

#### Binds

- Only Paizo material.
- Only abilities that are available to level 17 characters and only up to 8th-level spells can be used, but lower level is better.
- Wealth by level is average; million-gp items are off the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### As always, magic is the answer here.

There is a spell called [Terrain Bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/terrain-bond) which allow you to treat any terrain you are on as your favored terrain for level / 2 hours. Unfortunately, this is a Ranger only spell, so not very useful if you are trying to do this as a sorcerer.

So now we have 2 problems, let's tackle them one at a time:

> **1. Get the spell [Terrain Bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/terrain-bond)**
>
> - [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device): You are a sorcerer, you have the Charisma for this. Make a wand of [Terrain Bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/terrain-bond) and fire off a charge whenever you are caught without mountain / hill / cave. About the best option so far, lose almost nothing, but eat quite a bit of Wealth by Level (30000 gp / wand / 50 charges or 600 gp / charge)
> - [Ranger 13](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/): the vanilla way
> - [Arcane Savant 2](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/arcane-savant/): lose a caster level, but you can get some pretty nifty stuffs back if you play your cards right. If you want, you can steal [Terrain Bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/terrain-bond), and then 8 more spells from **any** lists. Available from Sorcerer 5
> - [Daivrat 5](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/daivrat/): Again, steal spell from other lists, but this time cost 2 spell slot level higher (so cast as 7th level spell). Overall worse due to losing more level, and it takes Sorcerer 7 to enter
> - [Samsaran](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-samsaran/) sorcerer: Use Mystic Past Life to steal [Terrain Bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/terrain-bond) to an divine class you want, and try to make a functional Theurge out of it. Very bad idea, but included for completeness
>
> **2. Getting [Favored Terrain (Mountain)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/)**
>
> Somehow this is even harder than pulling spells from other class lists (Why??, even if this is a feat, I would be hard-pressed to take it)
>
> - Emulate class feature from [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device): cost virtually nothing, but at minimum DC 23 (20 + [Ranger 3](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/)), possibly more
> - [Horizon Walker 1](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/apg/horizon-walker/): The least costly option I can find, entry early as level 6
> - Again, [Ranger 3](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/): the vanilla way
> - [Holy Guide Paladin 3](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo-paladin-archetypes/holy-guide/): not much better, but Paladin have better synergy to Sorcerer than Ranger
> - Rogue 2, get Rogue Talent [Terrain Mastery](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/terrain-mastery-ex/)

Combine the two best approach for the two steps, and we have [Use a Wand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device) whenever you need the caster level boost, beat a DC 23 check, and enjoy the caster level boost for 6 hours (minimum caster level 13).

PS: Checking back at the original version of the question, I suppose you can always [Move Earth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/move-earth/) to make your own hill if you have the time?

Comment: The spell *terrain bond*, I think, really *is* the best solution, but it's easier to use than the answer makes out. While a *wand of terrain bond* is expensive (600 gp/charge), it's less than 10% a level 17 PC's wealth, and the skill Use Magic Device can be used for activating it *and* emulating the class feature favored terrain. That seems far better than prestige classes or (brr!) throwing away caster levels!

Comment: Still need to waste 1 level for Favored Terrain (Mountain), but yeah, that is the best. What's wrong with prestige class, anyway?

Comment: Really, I think it may be even easier than this. The skill Use Magic Device "lets you use a magic item as if you had the… class features of another class…," so activate the *wand of terrain bond* while emulating the ranger class feature favored terrain (DC 20). Since the asker doesn't want to actually *have* the class feature favored terrain and, instead, only wants to benefit from the spell the *wand* holds as it's activated, employing the skill Use Magic Device this way should work fine.